# Unknown Problem - Need Help

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

This question is from an article I read online, titled: "Why I Will Never Have a Girlfriend" by Tristan Miller.

The author shows his work, step-by-step throughout most of the article, except during the conclusion, when he makes the following statement:

- "At first glance, a datable population of 18,726 may not seem like
  such a low number, but consider this: assuming I were to go on a
  blind date with a new girl about my age every week, I would have to
  date for 3,493 weeks before I found 1 of the 18,726."

He does not explain how he determined 3,493 is the number required to find 1 of the 18,726. I would really like to know. It seems similar to the Birthday Paradox, but I'm not certain?

Thank you in advance for any help / clue. I would *especially* appreciate anyone who explained, step-by-step how to figure this out, mathematically.

P.S. Apologies; I am not even certain exactly what type of math problem this even is, or what to call it.

Comment: You forgot to mention that he is considering a sample space of $65\,399\,083$ girls aged between $18$ and $25$.

Comment: My apologies. This problem honestly threw me through a loop; I can't believe I missed that! My mind was totally focused on this being some kind of combination/permutation problem that I was totally blind to the obvious solution. I thought that the author's conclusion section was a self-contained problem, and not related to the numerous previous statements he made earlier in the paper, thus I didn't realize the relevance.

Answer (score 3):

He considers

- the #girls his age: 65399083,
- and the #girls that are dateable (a good match for him) 18726.

If he dates blindly (uniformly at random from all girls his age) once every week, the probability he will meet a dateable girl on any given week is
$$
p = \frac{18726}{65399083}.
$$
The inverse $1/p$ is the expected time in weeks (mean of geometric distribution) till he meets a girl from the dateable set and is the number you want:
$$
\frac{1}{p} = \frac{65399083}{18726} = 3492.42139.
$$

Comment: Oh my god, lol. Thank you! I can't believe I missed that; I thought I was going crazy! I kept thinking there was some kind of secret mathematical principle I was missing!

Comment: How do I +1 you? Lol